# JQuery - Add active class based on URL but also different following sub paths

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not too savvy with JS so any solution to this would be great!

I'm currently adding an 'active' class to the nav items based on 'current' page as below:

```
$(function(){
    var current = location.pathname;
    $('#topiclinks a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is like this link, make it active
        if ($this.attr('href') === current) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
})
```

This is working for the nav items starting URL but they also have additional paths pages once using pagination (`/page/1` `/page/2` etc). Not only that, the first item has a different structure to the rest of the items.

I have these nav items:

"All"

Base URL = `/insight`

Additional path pages:

```
/insight/page/1

/insight/page/2
```

Then all the other items in the nav follow another path:

"Technology"

Base URL = `/insight/tag/technology`

Additional page paths:

```
/insight/tag/technology/page/1

/insight/tag/technology/page/2

/insight/tag/technology/page/3
```

"Support"

Base URL = `/insight/tag/support`

Additional page paths:

```
/insight/tag/support/page/1

/insight/tag/support/page/2

/insight/tag/support/page/3
```

Nav items are like this:

```
<a class="topic-link" href="/insight">All</a>
<a class="topic-link" href="/insight/tag/technology">Technology</a>
<a class="topic-link" href="/insight/tag/support">support</a>
```

The first nav item(All) has a different finishing path to the rest(when clicking through the pages) and the following ones include a part of that path but some additional (page)paths after.

Any idea how I can get the 'active' class to stay on the nav item when the URL path is the current but also a certain path after it? And for 2 different path structures exactly as outlined above?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

I converted my simpler script to jQuery to stay consistent with your code

```js
const getPath = url => {
  const path = new URL(url).pathname
  const parts = path.split("/");
  return parts.length < 3 || !parts.includes("tag") ? parts[1] : parts[3]
};

const path = getPath("https://yourserver.com/insight"); // getPath(location.href)

$("#nav a").each(function() {
  const lnkPath = getPath($(this).prop("href"));
  $(this).toggleClass("active", path === lnkPath)
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <a class="topic-link" href="/insight/page/1">All</a>
  <a class="topic-link" href="/insight/tag/technology">Technology</a>
  <a class="topic-link" href="/insight/tag/support">Support</a>
</div>
```

Change

```
const path = getPath("https://yourserver.com/insight/tag/support"); // getPath(location.href)
```

to

```
const path = getPath(location.href)
```

when happy

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! So this solution is working perfectly for 'Technology' and 'Support' paths but not for the first link which is the 'All' page(/insight) as this doesn't have the additional /tag path. The additional pages for 'All' are on /insight/page/1 /insight/page/2 etc This is slightly different to the others. Have you a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make all links with certain href to have "active" class then just use

```
$('a[href*="some_url"]').each(function() {
     $(this).addClass('active')
});
```